# .htaccess redirect 1 URI to SSL ( Using Query String Hiding )

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

I am trying to get something to work but I am going around in circles! Basically I am wanting to forward all page requests to the main index.php file using the ?request= query string. This all works perfectly.

However, I also want to forward all requests via https:// to http:// EXCEPT for a particular URI. It isn't working :-( Does anybody know why. I have tried all sorts of combinations from the internet. Here is the code in my .htaccess file:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Forward /index.php To / (without index.php)

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/this-is/my-secure-uri/?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: probably SSL is pointing to a different server? And what exactly is not working? For that single URI or for all HTTPS URIs?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain properly. All URLs except the stated uri /this-is/my-secure-uri/ forward successfully to a http:// version instead of https:// however I want the stated URI to remain on the https:// version

Comment: That's what you want. But what does not work?

Comment: I want the stated URI to remain on the https:// version <- This bit doesn't work

Comment: @user1461105 your rule looks ok, perhaps try changing this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/this-is/my-secure-uri/?.*$` to this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/this-is/my-secure-uri/?` not much different from each other. besides that the only rule that I would see that could make this go wrong is your php redirect, could you temporary comment that rule and test? If possible also access from a browser you haven't used yet to make sure you were not cached. due to the 301's you should always use 302 until the rule is working as you want it to so you don't get cached.